# Stop Code executing in query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I am checking for duplicates and it finds them and the If(isDuplicate) all works fine.
But the code continues and does all the submit because I am not telling it to stop.
How would I do this ? to stop and throw the error panel which it does but not submit?

```
_db.tbl_Localities.InsertOnSubmit(locality);

bool isDuplicate = _db.tbl_Localities
                    .Any(x => x.Locality == txt_Locality.Text);
if (isDuplicate)
{
    pnl_Message.Visible = true;
    lbl_message.Text = " Duplicate entry!";
    txt_Locality.Text = "";
}

// Save
// ====
_db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Probably move the Save part into an `else` statement so it only gets done if `isDuplicate` evaluates to false. It's hard to tell with out the rest of the code.

Comment: Thank you Its always the most obvious .. : -)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should handle `else` part of condition, or raise an exception if it's unexpected situation for your program:

```
_db.tbl_Localities.InsertOnSubmit(locality);

bool isDuplicate = _db.tbl_Localities
                    .Any(x => x.Locality == txt_Locality.Text);
if (isDuplicate)
{
    pnl_Message.Visible = true;
    lbl_message.Text = " Duplicate entry!";
    txt_Locality.Text = "";
}
else
{
    // Save
    // ====
    _db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `return;` in the if statement.

Comment: I would never advise using return statements other than at the end of a function.  They can be easily overlooked when trying to maintain code and make it much harder to refactor code at a later date.

Comment: @JustinHarvey well I think there lot of situations where `return` is appropriate. E.g. guard conditions, or returning from switch statements

Comment: @JustinHarvey you're probably correct here. I'm currently working in some code where they held to that believe. It only created nested if statements 10 levels deep, ther might be another problem here ;). Using return in a void espacially it's something to do with validation is better then nesting your if statements in my eyes. [Is it bad practice to use return inside a void method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283325/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-return-inside-a-void-method)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky, neither of your examples are an excuse in my view.

Comment: @Justin in my opinion the real problem is when you can't see all of the function in one screen. In cases where the function is well refactored I haven't had your problem.

Comment: @Aron, it sounds like you might be in trouble then if the function is more than one screen and not properly re-factored (as if that could ever happen).