# Can you use the "return" statement in C# methods declared as void?

Tags: c#, return, void

While reading an [MCSD](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/MCSD-Certification-Toolkit-Exam-70-483-Programming-in-C-.productCd-111861206X.html) study guide, I noticed the author said it was illegal to include a `return` statement in a method that declares the return type `void`.  However, when I created the following method Visual Studio didn't flag it in the editor nor did it fail to compile:

```
private void ReturnNothing()
{
    return;
}
```

What is the real answer then?  Is this legal?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it bad practice to use return inside a void method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283325/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-return-inside-a-void-method)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283325/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-return-inside-a-void-method for the answer, and reasons for & against it.

Comment: Don't think it's an exact duplicate of the previous 2 questions.  Not at all.

Comment: @MarioRossi - does not have to be *exact* duplicate... one studying for MCSD obviously looked it up if the statement is valid in C# specification, so seem to be perfectly fine to dup.

Comment: I don't want to post the actual name of the guide I was reading because I'm not sure if that is allowed and I don't want to accuse an author of publishing bad data.  I am simply unsure what the real answer is because the guide says it is illegal but Visual Studio allows me to use it.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I am not asking about C# bad practice; I want to know if it is legal or not.  I have used it before in C++ because I want to return from a method early.  If it is allowed I will publish the name of the book and quote from it.

Comment: @gonzobrains: The point is, the conclusion to that question was "no, it's not bad practice".  Ergo, it can't be illegal ;)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I see how you would conclude that, but when performing a Google search that question didn't come up as a result, so I think my question is still beneficial and not an exact duplicate.  Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: I have added a link to the guide I am referring to.

Comment: I'll add link I'm referring to too :)  http://www.bing.com/search?q=msdn+c%23+return+statement : one of the top links - " If the method is a `void` type, the return statement can be omitted."

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov bing...Bing...BING!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes it's definitely legal.

It's only illegal if you try to put a value after the return. This is wrong `return 0;`

Answer (score 0):

The author was probably referring to the form

```
return value ;
```

which is effectively invalid when return type == `void` (but valid and required when return type != `void`).

Comment: Actually, the author mentioned your scenario after the one to which I am referring.

Comment: @MarioRossi I'm only on the fourth chapter and I have already found a handful of typos, but this error just seemed to important to ignore.  This is why I decided to get opinions on SO.

Comment: The *requirements* of a non-void method are that (1) all `return` statements have an expression convertible to the return type, and (2) the end point of the method is not reachable. This does not logically imply that a non-void method must have a return! `int Foo() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }` meets both requirements; zero out of a possible zero return statements have an expression convertible to `int`, and the end point is not reachable, so it is legal.

Comment: @EricLippert  Yup, that's correct.  How to present it to a person who is just learning C# without distracting him/her from the core of the explanation, I don't know.  Perhaps through a good comment? :-)  Thanks many, Eric.