# if->return vs. if->else efficiency

Tags: performance, if-statement, return, compiler-optimization

If something needs to run only in a certain condition, which of these is more efficient:

**A.**

```c
if (condition) {
   // Do
   // things...
}
```

**B.**

```c
if (!condition) { return; }
// Do
// things...
```

Comment: Did you measure this? What did you find out?

Comment: It's a style thing. The performance is not relevant; both produce nearly identical machine code. If you want to avoid 'horizontal programming', you might want to prefer B to avoid nested conditions.

Comment: Check out http://jsperf.com/ when you have questions like this. Very useful site!

Comment: Which language and framework are you talking about? (Not that it even really matters, since the answer is the same for all languages and frameworks).

Comment: Your question does not show any research effort. Also you didn't specified the language. However you might be regarded as newbie and told that the concern is not worthwhile.

Comment: This question was spawned mainly from curiosity.
I did not specify specific language or framework because it was a general question.
I did do some measures in one language and framework and the results were the same (yeah well, unsurprisingly).
Obviously in most situations "you shouldn't really care",
though if there were/is a performance difference, then obviously in certain systems with certain configurations replacing the usage of one form with another *would* matter.
And in any rate, the question *was not* "Should anyone care about the difference of...".

Comment: Also, I understand of-course how this can be perceived as an "unnecessary" (or in worst words "stupid noobish") question, and expected (and got) at least one 'harsh response' about it, but it was asked out of genuine interest and desire to hear more expert people's takes on it (and got these as well, so thanks).

Comment: Also, B offers cleaner git difs as you are adding new lines as you add more checks rather than adding more indents so less code change in term of bytes in the file.

Answer (score 58):

They are equally efficient, but **B** is usually considered to give better readability, especially when used to eliminate several nested conditions.

Answer (score 31):

It's a style thing. Both produce (nearly?) identical machine code, and the performance should be the same.

Return early (B) to avoid nested conditions. For example, if you want to add exceptions while keeping a clear 'happy flow':

**A**:

```java
public String getDescription(MyObject obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return "";
    } else {
        if (!obj.isValid()) {
            return "invalid";
        } else {
            // happy flow
        }
    }
 }
```

**B**:

```java
public String getDescription(MyObject obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return "";
    }

    if (!obj.isValid()) {
        return "invalid";
    }

    // happy flow
 }
```

Comment: `The performance is not relevant` Whether or not the performance is relevant depends entirely on the use case.

Comment: Indeed, it is relevant. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 25):

Please pick the thing that is most readable. Performance optimizations at this level are hardly ever an issue. Even really performance sensitive parts of frameworks (such as the .NET framework) do not benefit from such an micro optimization.

Answer (score 21):

The real question is, should you really care?

I say NO! It's more important to have better readable code than doing some micro-optimization.

Answer (score 7):

While I agree that you should choose readability first, I'll go ahead and add a little info: In C#, there is no difference.  It compiles to the same thing (when optimized by building Release mode).  Other languages?  Who knows, I'm sure some of them consider it different, but the chances that you actually need to be concerned about it is slim to none.

Answer (score 0):

Performance is more or less the same in both the cases. Therefore it becomes more of a style or preference question.

I personally prefer writing if--> return i.e. case B because it makes the code to look cleaner and easy to read specially if the code comprises of complex nested conditions.