# How to break the Parallel.ForEachAsync loop, not cancel it?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-6.0, parallel.foreachasync

In .NET 5 we had `Parallel.ForEach` which you were able to use `ParallelLoopState.Break()` method to stop additional iterations from processing. Allowing current ones to complete processing.

But the new .NET 6 `Parallel.ForEachAsync` does not have the `ParallelLoopState` class so we can't break it like we could with `Parallel.ForEach`. So is there a way to perform the same break functionality in `ForEachAsync`? `CancellationToken` passed to the func I don't believe is the right way since your not trying to cancel the running loop but preventing additional iterations from starting.

Something like this functionality but for the async version:

```
int count = 0;
Parallel.ForEach(enumerateFiles, new ParallelOptions() { CancellationToken = cancellationToken},
    (file, state) =>
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref count);
        if (count >= MaxFilesToProcess)
        {
            state.Break();
        }
...
```

As a workaround I can probably use `.Take([xx])` on the `TSource` before it is passed into the parallel loop but that might not be an option for a complex condition to break on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The asynchronous API [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync) does not offer the `Stop`/`Break` functionality of its synchronous counterpart.

One way to replicate this functionality is to use a `bool` flag in combination with the [`TakeWhile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.takewhile) LINQ operator:

```
bool breakFlag = false;
await Parallel.ForEachAsync(
    source.TakeWhile(_ => !Volatile.Read(ref breakFlag)),
    async (item, ct) =>
{
    // ...
    if (condition) Volatile.Write(ref breakFlag, true);
    // ...
});
```

The `Parallel.ForEachAsync` does not buffer aggressively elements from the source sequence¹, like the `Parallel.ForEach` does, so as soon as the condition is met, no more asynchronous operations are going to start.

Is case the `source` is an asynchronous enumerable (`IAsyncEnumerable<T>`), there is a compatible [`TakeWhile`](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/main/Ix.NET/Source/System.Linq.Async/System/Linq/Operators/TakeWhile.cs) operator with identical functionality in the [System.Linq.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async) package.

¹ <sub>At least not today (.NET 6). This behavior is [not documented or guaranteed](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/72806).</sub>

Comment: When I implemented it for ForEachAsync, at first it didn't work at all. My source was an OrdredParallelQuery type from PLINQ. I changed the source to an Array and that made it so it runs once for each Logical Processor I have if I set the MaxFilesToProcess to 1.  Which makes sense since it must start all before one gets to the break condition. But when I set MaxFilesToProcess for more than the number of Logical Processors, it works ok.

Comment: @stymie2 combining a synchronous (PLINQ) and an asynchronous technology (`Parallel.ForEachAsync`) may have unexpected repercussions. You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62035864/design-help-for-parallel-processing-azure-blob-and-bulk-copy-to-sql-database-c/62041200#62041200) some of the adjustments that you can do to a PLINQ query, in order to behave desirably in a pipeline. If you have any other issues, you could consider posting a new question.