# How to use CancellationTokenSource in Parallel.ForEachAsync

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, cancellationtokensource, parallel.foreachasync

Having this handler :

```
public async Task<Result> Handle(MyQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
     var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

     await Parallel.ForEachAsync(myList, async (objectId, _) =>
     {
         var result = await _service.GetObject(objectId);

         if (result.Any())
         {
             cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
         }
     });

     if (cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested) return Result.Fail("Error message.");

     return Result.Ok();
}
```

This works, but was wondering if I'm using `CancellationTokenSource` correct here?

Comment: What is the goal of this code? If you need to report that any of the iterations has "result.Any()" then just set boolean variable.

Comment: If it detects that a record exist in ``result`` a ``Result.Fail("");`` needs to be returned and stop the loop.

Comment: If you need to stop the loop you should pass `cancellationTokenSource.Token` to the appropriate overload of `ForEachAsync()`. You will then need to catch `OperationCanceledException` outside the loop.

Comment: Your current implementation will not stop the loop.

Comment: Related: [Stop Parallel.ForEachAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70827715/stop-parallel-foreachasync) and also [How to break the Parallel.ForEachAsync loop, not cancel it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71072305/how-to-break-the-parallel-foreachasync-loop-not-cancel-it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using `CancellationTokenSource` just as a boolean variable, if the goal is to cancel the batch when some condition is met then the usage is completely wrong, you need to pass token to the `ForEachAsync` call (and ideally handle cancellation token in the body). Something along these lines:

```cs
try
{
    await Parallel.ForEachAsync(myList, cancellationTokenSource.Token, async (objectId, ct) =>
    {
        // pass the cancellation token
        var result = await _service.GetObject(objectId, ct);

        if (result.Any())
        {
            cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        }
    });
}
catch (OperationCanceledException e)
{
    Result.Fail("Error message.");
}
```

And as [@Magnus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/468973/magnus) correctly points out - you should use the cancellation token passed to your `Handle` method (`CancellationToken cancellationToken`) also:

```cs
using var cancellationTokenSource = 
    CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken);
// ...
```

See also:

- [Using Parallel.ForEachAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70249422/2501279)
- [The need for two cancellation tokens in .NET 6 Parallel.ForEachAsync?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70191295/2501279)

Comment: And probably a good idea to combine it with the incoming ct. `var cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedToken(cancellationToken)`