# How do I cancel an async List<T>.ForEach

Tags: c#, async-await

I have the following code:

```
contact.AddressList.ForEach(async (address) =>
{
    //......
    returnValues = await _apiDataService.CallEndPointAPIAsync(
        Contact, token, "ContactApiEndpoint");
    if (returnValues.Response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        //jump out of here
    }
});
```

If for any reason the call, doesn't return ok, I want to jump of here, I thought I'd get away with `break;` but that's not allowed at this point.

Comment: Convert to it to a regular "for each". By the way the code inside the foreach block is not awaited in the function it is in since `contact.AddressList.ForEach` is not awaited. (and can not be)

Comment: My advice: never use the `ForEach` extension, it is really pointless. It doesn't make your code more readable, it's slower since it needs to create a lambda, there are side effects such as closures, and arguably goes against Linq principles (i.e. it's not a query, you can mutate the data)

Comment: And it doesn't work properly with `async` code anyway

Comment: @DavidG: `ForEach` isn't a LINQ extension method, it's an own method of `List<T>`. Still valid comment though, and I agree.

Comment: what exactly do you want to *achieve* by the `break`? Should all the other requests be cancelled?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Execute these requests one after the other and stop when at the first failing? Then use a standard `for` or `foreach` loop. Execute them in parallel? Then what happens to the other requests, when one fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

Just use a normal `foreach` loop as mentioned in various comments:

```
foreach (var address in contact.AddressList)
{
    ......
    returnValues = await _apiDataService.CallEndPointAPIAsync(Contact, token, "ContactApiEndpoint");
    if (returnValues.Response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: however that will effectivly run all the tasks synchronously one after the other. We don't know if that is a problem, though.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain So does for `ForEach` - It's not `Parallel.ForEach`

Comment: I know, that's why I asked about OPs actual *intent*. No idea why OP uses `ForEach` in the first place. Chances are he/she actually wants some parallelilsm.

Comment: @YungDeiza but not if the Action passed into `ForEach` is `async`. In that case, it will just start each of the actions but don't await them ...

Comment: @derpirscher true

Comment: My assumption is that if you want to cancel the loop due to the failure of an operation within the loop then it should be run synchronously - otherwise you should continue other operations irrespective of any failure in any individual operation.

Comment: ​​@MakePeaceGreatAgain it's sequentially, not synchronously. The tasks run sequentially one after the other.

Comment: This one does it...I dont need to do it parallel as there will only be max 5 awaits and the idea is that I want to stop if any fail.

Comment: @bilpor you might find this question interesting: [Stop Parallel.ForEachAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70827715/stop-parallel-foreachasync).