# Execute a binary tmpfile in C++

Tags: c++, exe, temporary-files

My objective is to wrap a `.exe` file in another `.exe` file. Whenever the wrapper `.exe` is launched, the embedded `.exe` should be launched.
I have added the binary file as a resource.
Now I want to load the file as a tmpfile and use the `system()` function or some alternative to execute the binary file. However, I am not able to get the filename of the tmpfile. I cannot use tmpnam because it will only return a filename but not create an actual temporary file.

My code so far :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HRSRC hRes = FindResource(0, MAKEINTRESOURCE(1), RT_RCDATA);
    HGLOBAL hMem = LoadResource(0, hRes);
    void* pMem = LockResource(hMem);
    DWORD size = SizeofResource(0, hRes);

    FILE * f = tmpfile();
    fwrite(pMem, size, 1, f);
    fclose(f);

    return 0;
}
```

Please do help me.
Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need this program embedded as a resource? Can't you simply install it besides your main program?

Comment: You are using WinAPI, so you can use GetTempFileName() + GetTempPath() for generating temporary file name. Then create file with fopen() with that generated file name for binary writing. An then use your fwrite() + fclose(). And then ShellExecute() for running app

Answer (score 2):

According to this:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tmpfile.3.html

the file gets deleted after closing, so use `fflush` instead of `fclose` (run the `fclose` after the embedded `exe` has finished). Then find some information about the filename here:

[Is there a way to get the filename from a `FILE*`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862327/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-filename-from-a-file)