# Creating a GIO GFile or GInputStream from std::FILE*

Tags: c++, c, file, gio

I have to connect two APIs, which use different structures to describe files. One provides me with a [std::FILE*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c) and the second one expects a [GFile*](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GFile.html#GFile-struct) or [GInputStream*](https://developer.gnome.org/gio//2.56/GInputStream.html) belonging to the [GIO](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/). Is there a straightforward way to create either object from the raw file pointer which I receive?

```cpp
void my_function(std::FILE * file) {

GFile * gfile = some_creator_method(file);
//or alternatively
GInputStream * ginput = some_stream_creator_method(file);

//...
//pass the GFile to the other library interface
//either using:
interface_function(gfile);
//or using
interface_stream_function(ginput);
}

//The interface function signatures I want to pass the parameter to:

void interface_function(GFile * f);

void interface_stream_function(GInputStream * is);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to re-use the underlying file handle, you will need to go platform-specific.

- On POSIX: [`fileno`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fileno) in combination with [`g_unix_input_stream_new`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GUnixInputStream.html#g-unix-input-stream-new)
- On Windows: [`_get_osfhandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/get-osfhandle?view=vs-2019) in combination with [`g_win32_input_stream_new`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio//2.44/gio-GWin32InputStream.html#g-win32-input-stream-new)

For example like this:

```
void my_method(FILE* file) {
#ifdef _WIN32
    GInputStream* ginput = g_win32_input_stream_new(_get_osfhandle(file), false);
#else
    GInputStream* ginput = g_unix_input_stream_new(fileno(file), false);
#endif

    . . .
    . . .

    g_input_stream_close(ginput, nullptr, nullptr);
}
```

Keep in mind though that `file` should be kept open for as long as `ginput` is in use.

Comment: If I were being really fussy, I'd have to say that this doesn't fully answer the question, because it doesn't provide a `GFile *`. But it's not clear whether the OP actually wants the `GFile *`, or just a way to get a `GInputStream *`.

Comment: @KevinBoone `GFile` is not an equivalent of `FILE`; `GFile` does not represent an open file, merely file metadata (name, location). On the other hand, `FILE` represents *only* an open file, without any metadata (well, technically on Linux it's sometimes possible to retrieve the file name from a file descriptor, but I wouldn't recommend it).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but @KevinBoone is right and it does not quite solve my problem. The interface I want to call really expects a GFile * or GInputStream *. I will edit my question to make that clearer.

Comment: @geo -- Problem is that a `GFile *` is not really analogous to a `FILE *` -- `GFile` is more like a pathname than a stream. If you have an API that takes a `GInputStream *` then the method suggested by @rustyx should work, no?

Comment: So I can pass a GUnixInputStream* instead of a GInputStream*? (btw: the library interface itself is exposed in C).

Comment: @geo `GWin32InputStream` and `GUnixInputStream` both inherit from `GInputStream`, you can supply them anywhere `GInputStream*` is expected.

Comment: Is there any way to get a GFile from a file? My interface needs me to set a GFile *and* a GInputStream after all. This is truly driving me insane....

Comment: You can create a `GFile` from a file path. If you don't want to pass the file path to your function, you need to somehow get the file path from `FILE*`, which is non-trivial. You can get some inspiration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58081928/c-print-file-path-from-file) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfinalpathnamebyhandlew)