# How to get a filename from an IO object in ruby

Tags: ruby, io

In ruby...

I have an IO object created by an external process, which I need to get the file name from.
However I only seem to be able to get the File descriptor (3), which is not very useful to me.

Is there a way to get the filename from this object or even to get a File Object?

I am getting the IO object from notifier. So this may be a way of getting the file path as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a similar question on [how to get a the filename in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188757/getting-filename-from-file-descriptor-in-c), I will present here the answer to this question in a ruby way.

## Getting the filename in Linux

Suppose `io` is your IO Object. The following code gives you the filename.

```
File.readlink("/proc/self/fd/#{io.fileno}")
```

This does not work for example if the file was removed after the io object was created for it. With this solution you have the filename, but not an File object.

## Getting a File object which does not know the filename

The method `IO#for_fd` can create an IO and it's subclasses for any given integer filedescriptor. Your get your File object for your fd by doing:

```
File.for_fd(io.fileno)
```

Unfortunely this File object does not know the filename.

```
File.for_fd(io.fileno).path # => nil
```

I scanned through the ruby-1.9.2 sources. There seems to be no way in pure ruby to manipulate the path after the file object was created.

## Getting a File object which does know the filename

An extension to ruby can be created in C which first calls `File#for_fd` and afterwards manipulates the Files internal data structures. This sourcecode does work for ruby-1.9.2, for other versions of ruby it may has to be adjustet.

```
#include "ruby.h"
#include "ruby/io.h"

VALUE file_fd_filename(VALUE self, VALUE fd, VALUE filename) {
    VALUE file= rb_funcall3(self, rb_intern("for_fd"), 1, &fd);
    rb_io_t *fptr= RFILE(rb_io_taint_check(file))->fptr;
    fptr->pathv= rb_str_dup(filename);
    return file;
}

void Init_filename() {

    rb_define_singleton_method(rb_cFile, "for_fd_with_filename", file_fd_filename, 2);

}
```

Now you can do after compiling:

```
require "./filename"
f= File.for_fd_with_filename(io.fileno, File.readlink("/proc/self/fd/#{io.fileno}"))
f.path # => the filename
```

The readlink could also be put into the `File#for_fd_with_filename` definiton. This examples is just to show how it works.

Comment: Won’t work on BSD and, by extension, on OS X, as these don’t  have a `/proc` pseudo filesystem (yes, there is procfs, but that is not mounted by default in FreeBSD – besides being phased out – and decidedly non trivial to install under OS X).

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the IO object represents a File you could try something like this

```
path = io.path if io.respond_to?(:path)
```

[See documentation for File#path](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/File.html#method-i-path)

Comment: The IO Object doesn't represent a File Object, it represents an IO object. I want to get a file object from this. The above won't work as io does not respond to path

Comment: This also won't work on a `File` object if somebody renames the file out from under you -- `f.path` will return the old path.