# How can I programmatically get the list of open file descriptors for a given PID on OS X?

Tags: c, macos, pid, file-descriptor

Everything I've seen says to use `lsof -p`, but I'm looking for something that doesn't require a fork/exec.

For example on Linux one can simply walk `/proc/{pid}/fd`.

Comment: Have you checked out the [lsof source code](http://people.freebsd.org/~abe/)?

Comment: I dug into it for 15 minutes or so, but I am pretty terrible at C and couldn't make much sense of it.  I'll keep poking at it, and if I come up with something, I'll post it as an answer myself :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can [use `proc_pidinfo`](http://blog.palominolabs.com/2012/06/19/getting-the-files-being-used-by-a-process-on-mac-os-x/) with the `PROC_PIDLISTFDS` option to enumerate the files used by a given process. You can then use `proc_pidfdinfo` on each file in turn with the `PROC_PIDFDVNODEPATHINFO` option to get its path.

Comment: Are there any good man pages or other documentation on this API?  I've been ctags-ing my way round /usr/include and read that example you provided, but it's pretty terse.

Comment: There's not any documentation that I'm aware. `sys/proc_info.h` seems relatively self-explanatory in terms of interpreting the information available from the system calls, and the implementation of the system calls is available in the kernel open source if you want to understand more about how it all works.

Comment: There is now whole source of lsof tool on github: https://github.com/lsof-org/lsof which covers basically everything regarding getting information about the process FDs and more