# In Python 2, can I get the real path of a file object after changing directories?

Tags: python

In Python 2, is it possible to get the real path of a file object after an `os.chdir()`? Consider:

```
$ python
>>> f = file('abc', 'w')
>>> f.name
'abc'
>>> from os import path
>>> path.realpath(f.name)
'/home/username/src/python/abc'
>>> os.chdir('..')
>>> path.realpath(f.name)
'/home/username/src/abc'
```

The first call to `realpath` returns the path of the file on disk, but the second one does not. Is there any way to get the path of the disk file after the `chdir`? Ideally, I'd like a general answer, one that would work even if I didn't create the file object myself.

I don't have any actual use case for this, I'm just curious.

Comment: `os.path.realpath()` works on strings, not on file objects. Therefore, it has no idea where in the file system your file is. But you do.

Comment: Oh, the joys of relative file paths. You gave `realpath()` a string, not anything close to a location.

Comment: This is a bug IMHO - you can't, in general, go from a file handle to a file name. Therefore, python must store the name you open it with; it should store the `realpath`.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain: If you open the file, you obviously know the path. So why should Python store it *again*?`

Comment: @TimPietzcker That is a different question; I simply said if it stores it at all, it should store the `realpath`.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain : `f.name` contains only `'abc'`, with no notion of this being a file or not.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain: The property is explicitly documented as the argument you passed to `open()`.

Answer (score 1):

> ...that works if I create the file object myself. But what if I
>   didn't? What if I received it in a function? I'd prefer a more general
>   answer (and I've edited the question to reflect that).

I don't think the full path is likely to be stored anywhere in the Python internals, but you can ask the OS for the path, based on the file descriptor.

This should work for Linux...

```
>>> import os
>>> os.chdir('/tmp')
>>> f = open('foo', 'w')
>>> os.chdir('/')
>>> os.readlink('/proc/%d/fd/%d' % (os.getpid(), f.fileno()))
'/tmp/foo'
```

Not sure about Windows.

Comment: you could use `/proc/self/`. See [Getting Filename from file descriptor in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1188757/4279) (there are also answers for Windows and OSX).

Answer (score 0):

sure

```
f=file(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"fname"),"w")

print f.name
```

as long as you use an absolute path when you initialize it

as  Martijn Pieters points out you could also do

```
f=file(os.path.abspath('fname'),"w")  #or os.path.realpath , etc

print f.name
```

Comment: or better still, use `os.path.abspath('fname')`

Comment: Under the hood, `os.path.abspath('fname')` is effectively `os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'fname')`, but with nicer handling of relative paths including `.` and `..` references.

Comment: True, that works if I create the file object myself. But what if I didn't? What if I received it in a function? I'd prefer a more general answer (and I've edited the question to reflect that).

Comment: provide a helper function called createFile(fname) or something that ensures an absolute path on the file object returned ...