# How do I detect a change to the filename of an open file in Golang

Tags: go

Using Go, I was writing a small utility that in part needs to notice if the filename of an open file changes. The below code illustrates the approach I tried:

```
package main

import "os"
import "fmt"
import "time"

func main() {

    path := "data.txt"
    file, _ := os.Open(path)

    for {
        details, _ := file.Stat()
        fmt.Println(details.Name())
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    }
}
```

This just starts an endless loop, running `file.Stat()` to obtain file details every 5 seconds and then printing out the name. However, despite changing the filename as this is running, the output of the above does not change.

replacing `details.Name()` with `details.Size()` does however notice changes to the filesize.

Is this simply a bug in my version of Go, or am I just doing things wrong? I cannot find mention of such an issue anywhere offhand.

I am running this on a Mac, with Go version 1.1.1 (darwin/amd64).

Thanks in advance for any replies :)

Comment: [fsnotify](https://github.com/howeyc/fsnotify) might help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Unix-like operating systems, once you open a file it is no longer tied to a name. The file-descripter you get is only tied to the inode of the file you open. All meta-data of a file is associated with the inode. There is no simple way to get the name of a file from the inode, thus what you want is impossible, except if the operating system you are using provides a special means to do that.

Also: What filename do you want to observe? A file could have multiple names or no name at all (such as a typical temporary file).

The only thing I think you could do is:

- Open the file, remember the filename
- periodically call Stat on the filename to see whether the inode matches
- if the inode is different, your file has been moved

This does however, not give you the new filename. Such a thing is impossible to do portably.

Answer (score 2):

Alas it is quite a difficult problem to find the name of an open file in general.

All `file.Name()` does is this ([see the docs](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Name))

```
// Name returns the name of the file as presented to Open.
func (f *File) Name() string { return f.name }
```

You might want to check out this question for some ideas: [Getting Filename from file descriptor in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188757/getting-filename-from-file-descriptor-in-c).  There are solutions for Linux, Windows and Mac in the answers.

Comment: As OP described, file.Name() does not change for him if the file is renamed. I think this answer does not solve the question OP asked.

Comment: The question was explain why the Name() doesn't change.  I think the quote from the docs answers that quite well!