# How can I get file name and path from file descriptor?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I am developing a C application for linux in which I need the open file lists using process ids. I am traversing `/proc/pid/fd` directory for file descriptor. But how can I know file path and file name from file descriptor? Or any other method or api function should I use?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) describes `/proc/pid/fd/` as:

> This is a subdirectory containing one entry for each file
>                 which the process has open, named by its file descriptor, and
>                 which is a symbolic link to the actual file.

Therefore, you can call [`stat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) on each entry and retrieve metadata about the file.

Comment: If you want information about the link, you need lstat, not stat.

Comment: `touch foo;` [process opens foo]; `ln foo bar`; [`foo` and `bar` point to the same file content now ]; `rm foo` ; [/proc/pid/fd/XX symlink is dead now, though the file itself is still accessible as `bar`];

Comment: @ArtemB: That's right, you cannot access those "walking dead" files from outside the process that owns it (imagine you didn't even have `bar`). I believe that's by design, for security reasons.

Comment: @KerrekSB : What about HP-UX or Solaris?

Answer (score 0):

you can use: `fcntl`'s `F_GETPATH`

code:

```c
#include <sys/syslimits.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

const char* curDir = "/private/var/mobile/Library/“;

int curDirFd = open(curDir, O_RDONLY);

        // for debug: get file path from fd
        char filePath[PATH_MAX];
        int fcntlRet = fcntl(curDirFd, F_GETPATH, filePath);
        const int FCNTL_FAILED = -1;
        if (fcntlRet != FCNTL_FAILED){
            NSLog(@"fcntl OK: curDirFd=%d -> filePath=%s", curDirFd, filePath);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"fcntl fail for curDirFd=%d", curDirFd);
        }
```

output:

```
curDir=/private/./var/../var/mobile/Library/./ -> curDirFd=4
fcntl OK: curDirFd=4 -> filePath=/private/var/mobile/Library
```

refer: [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13544447/1616263)

Comment: This wouldn't work on Linux because F_GETPATH is not defined from what I can tell.