# How to get the argument after the less than symbol (<) in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-arguments

For example, I have

```
./run.sh < file.dat
```

How do I get the argument "file.dat" in run.sh?

Comment: What follows the `<` is not an argument to `./run.sh`.  The contents of `file.dat` are streamed into the command by bash (or whatever shell you use), and the command never knows about it.

Comment: You don't. `bash` has already attached that file to `stdin`

Comment: @harpo, I think he wants to know whether there's a way to grab it anyways. :)

Comment: Do you want the name, or are the file's contents really what matter? If you want the file's contents, just read from stdin the usual way. Also, what should happen if input isn't redirected, or if it comes from a pipe?

Comment: @user2357112 I just want the name but not the content, since I need to pass it to other java/python/C program in bash script.

Comment: @Fei: It sounds like you should be taking this input as an actual argument, rather than by redirecting stdin.

Comment: @user2357112 I hope I could, but the project requirement is to use strict "./run.sh < file.dat" form.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Filename from file descriptor in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188757/getting-filename-from-file-descriptor-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Linux, you can get this data from `/proc`:

```
#!/bin/bash
readlink /proc/$$/fd/0
```

This will print the path of whatever's opened as stdin, such as `file.dat` in your example.

Note that getting the filename this way is not the correct way of working with the file, and should be used purely for debugging and informational purposes.

To work with the data you should instead simply read from stdin. For example, read lines with `IFS= read -r myline; echo "$myline"` to read a single line, or `mydata=$(cat); echo "$mydata"` to read all of it.

Comment: +1; handy to know. Caveat: On some Linux flavors - e.g., Ubuntu 12.04 - `realpath` is an `alias`, not an executable, so unless you take steps to make that alias available in your script, this won't work. On said platform the alias is defined as `alias realpath='python -c '\''import os, sys; print os.path.realpath(sys.argv[1])'\'''`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Excellent pointer, thanks. AFAIK (I do not know for sure), all Linux flavors have a `readlink` utility, so `readlink /dev/fd/0` is the more portable choice.