# get destination of stderr redirect in python, linux

Tags: python, linux

I'm redirecting stderr to a file with

```
python foo.py 2> stderror.txt
```

Once the script is partway done, I want to move `stderror.txt` with

```
subprocess.call(['cp', 'stderror.txt', 'destination.txt'])
```

My question - what if I redirected stderr to `results/stderror.txt`? Is there a way to programmatically get the destination of a redirect from within the script?

(Note: I know that this isn't really the way to solve my problem. Just curious.)

Answer (score 2):

One possible way is to read the link `/proc/<pid>/fd/2`:

```py
os.readlink("/proc/%d/fd/2" % os.getpid())
```

A shortcut is to use `/proc/self/fd/2`. In the unredirected case, you'll get some special file in `/dev`, usually a pseudo terminal. For other OSes, see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188757/getting-filename-from-file-descriptor-in-c).

Comment: Of course, this only works on linux-like systems that support the `/proc` filesystem.

Comment: `/proc/self` is a symlink to the `/proc/<pid>` dir of the calling process.  Just FYI