# Make std::cout do not fail with O_NONBLOCK or make stdin O_NONBLOCK keeping stdout blocking?

Tags: c++, stdout, iostream, nonblocking, fcntl

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
        // Make stdin non-blocking
        fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_SETFL, fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_GETFL) | O_NONBLOCK);

        printf("stdout O_NONBLOCK is: %d\n", fcntl(STDOUT_FILENO, F_GETFL) & O_NONBLOCK);
        printf("stdin O_NONBLOCK is: %d\n",  fcntl(STDIN_FILENO , F_GETFL) & O_NONBLOCK);

        for(int i=0; i<16; i++){
            cout<<"  "<<"fgvbhln;j;jblhcbwnoi wiejnocje ocweo cewoj coj weoj cowejojewohewouspuweoche njwpihbeh wjo erouhep hv reough er "<<endl;
        }
        bool cerrfail=cerr.fail(), coutfail=cout.fail();
        flush(cout); flush(clog); flush(cerr);
        cout.clear(); cerr.clear(); clog.clear();
        cerr<<"\ncerr.fail():"<<cerrfail<<" cout.fail():"<<coutfail<<endl;
}
```

possible output:

> Compiler G++ 9.3
> MacOS Mojave 10.14.6

```
stdout O_NONBLOCK is: 4
stdin O_NONBLOCK is: 4
  fgvbhln;j;jblhcbwnoi wiejnocje ocweo cewoj coj weoj cowejojewohewouspuweoche njwpihbeh wjo erouhep hv reough er 
  fgvbhln;j;jblhcbwnoi wiejnocje ocweo cewoj coj weoj cowejojewohewouspuweoche njwpihbeh wjo erouhep hv reough er 
  fgvbhln;j;jblhcbwnoi wiejnocje ocweo cewoj coj weoj cowejojewohewouspuweoche njwpihbeh wjo erouhep hv reough er 
  fgvbhln;j;jblhcbwnoi wiejnocje ocweo cewoj coj weoj cowejojewohewouspuweoche njwpihbeh wjo erouhep hv reough er 
  fgvbhln;j;jblhcbwnoi wiejnocje ocweo cewoj coj weoj cowejojewohewouspuweoche njwpihbeh wjo erouhep hv reough er 
  fgvbhln;j;jblhcbwnoi wiejnocje ocweo cewoj coj weoj cowejojewohewouspuweoche njwpihbeh wjo erouhep hv reough er 
  fgvbhln;j;jblhcbwnoi wiejnocje ocweo cewoj coj weoj cowejojewohewouspuweoche njwpihbeh wjo erouhep hv reough er 
  fgvbhln;j;jblhcbwnoi wiejnocje ocweo cewoj coj weoj cowejojewohewouspuweoche njwpihbeh wjo erouhep hv reough er 
  fgvbhln;j;jblhcbwnoi wiejnocje ocweo cewoj coj weoj cowejojewohewouspuweoche njwpihbeh wjo ero
cerr.fail():0 cout.fail():1
```

fails because of `fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_SETFL, fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_GETFL) | O_NONBLOCK);`

Why? How to fix keeping stdin non-block?

update.
**Why?** because setting stdin O_NONBLOCK also makes stdout O_NONBLOCK. And std::out receives some ASYNC error code (like ETRYAGAIN) in its internals.

I see two solutions:

- make std::cout do not fail with O_NONBLOCK
- make stdin O_NONBLOCK keeping stdout blocking?

update2.
The issue appears on MacOS only. Does not on Linux amd64 and does not on Linux MIPS (Atheros).

Comment: Is stdout also non-blocking after your call? https://stackoverflow.com/q/23865898/1133144

Comment: Yes. It sets non-block to both `stdout O_NONBLOCK is: 4
stdin O_NONBLOCK is: 4`

Comment: What compiler, version, compiler options are you using? What platform are you on? What implementation of C and C++ standard libraries are you using? I think, if this is specific to OSX, consider tagging it with OSX. I can't reproduce on linux with glibc, (on linux `O_NONBLOCK = 2048`).

Comment: @KamilCuk, thank you for response, I added details about my system.

Comment: Your update doesn't really explain why you want `stdout` to be non-blocking. What would be the advantage of this? If attempting to output is generating an error code, then it sounds like you have an X-Y problem and should fix *that* instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard streams do not support non-blocking file descriptors, those are beyond the scope of the C++ standard.

If you insist on using non-blocking file descriptors with standard streams, then you need to implement a stream buffer that can read/write non-blocking file descriptors. You can do that from scratch by deriving [`std::basic_streambuf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf) and implementing its virtual functions or use excellent [Boost.Iostreams](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html)
 to greatly reduce the amount and complexity of boilerplate code you'd otherwise have to write. And then replace the buffer of `std::cout`, `std::cin` and friends with your special stream buffer with a call to `std::basic_ios<>::rdbuf`.

Even then, using `std::istream` and `std::ostream` interfaces you wouldn't be able to distinguish end-of-file from `EAGAIN`.

---

You may like to elaborate what problem you are trying to solve because your current solution creates more problems.

Comment: Thank you. I found a way to decline non-blocking stdin, now stdout works fine.