# How do I find the case-preserved name of a file in Perl?

Tags: perl, filesystems, filenames, case-insensitive

On a case-insensitive file system, such as NTFS or HFS+, given the name of a file, what is the most efficient way to determine the case-preserved version of the file name?

Consider on HFS+ (Mac OS X):

```
> perl -E 'say "yes" if -e "/TMP"'
yes
```

It says it exists, of course, but I have no idea how its case is preserved. What's the most efficient way to determine the actual case?

What I've tried so far:

- `glob` with character classes: It doesn't work on Windows:

  ```
  > perl -E "say for glob "C:\\Perl"
  C:\Perl
  > perl -E "say for glob "C:\\[Pp][Ee][Rr][Ll]"
  ```

  Note the lack of output from that last command. :-(
- `opendir`/`readdir`: Works, but seems rather inefficient to read an entire directory:

  ```
    > perl -E "opendir my $dh, 'C:\\'; say for grep { lc $_ eq 'perl' } readdir $dh; close $dh"
  Perl
  ```

Is it crazy to think that there ought to be some core operating system instructions or something to get at this information more efficiently?

Comment: This question might help for HFS+: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13544447/702638

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `opendir`/`readdir`/`grep` solution is the proper one. [Via Twitter](https://twitter.com/neilbowers/status/568467649153384448), Neil Bowers points to this quotation from [perlport](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html#System-Interaction):

> Don't count on filename globbing. Use `opendir`, `readdir`, and `closedir` instead.

[@miyagawa](/users/612142/miyagawa), also [via Twitter](https://twitter.com/miyagawa/status/568468344300400641), says that there is no system call for this, and if there was, it wouldn't be portable.

And given that [@mob's answer](/a/28614219/79202) and comments [from David Golden](https://twitter.com/xdg/status/568213222119096321) suggest that `glob` would be more expensive than `opendir`, `readdir`, anyway, there just seems to be no other way around it.

So here's the function I wrote to find all the cases for a given basename in a directory:

```
sub _actual_filenames {
    my $dir = shift;
    my $fn = lc shift;
    opendir my $dh, $dir or return;
    return map { File::Spec->catdir($dir, $_) }
        grep { lc $_  eq $fn } readdir $dh;
}
```

Comment: Fails for `C:\PROGRA~1` on Windows. At the very least, it should return `C:\PROGRA~1`, but `C:\Program Files` would be far better.

Answer (score 4):

On Windows,

```
>perl -MWin32 -E"say Win32::GetLongPathName($ARGV[0])" "C:\PROGRAM FILES"
C:\Program Files

>perl -MWin32 -E"say Win32::GetLongPathName($ARGV[0])" C:\PROGRA~1
C:\Program Files
```

On unix, `fcntl`'s [`F_GETPATH`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13544447/589924) function will do.

Comment: "F_GETPATH" is not exported by the Fcntl module

Comment: Since you're going to have to write some C to get the constant, you might as well write the function in C.

Comment: I'm not gonna add C to Pod::Simple. My dumb heuristic will have to do for now.

Comment: huh? A second ago, you were ok with it. (What do you think `GetLongPathName` is written in?) If you want to access the system, it's rather hard to avoid C.

Comment: I'm fine to use modules written in C, but have no plans to add C/XS to Pod::Simple. If F_GETPATH was in the Functl module, I might use it. But it's not.

Comment: So you don't mind using the C/XS code, as long as it's not in Pod::Simple... Who said anything about putting it in Pod::Simple?

Comment: If I don't put it in Pod::Simple, since Pod::Simple is in core, I need to use something that's in core. Sounds like there isn't anything unless someone writes a module and gets it into core. But maybe I'm missing something? (Seems likely…)

Comment: @theory, Or add the constant to Fcntl

Comment: And then it would work only in the latest version of Perl to include that change.

Comment: Right, ok, so the constant approach won't work (on its own). Note that Win32.pm isn't in core either.

Comment: Yeah, so I think [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28614580/79202) is good enough for Pod::Simple.

Comment: Just fall back to returning the input rather than nothing when there's no match.

Answer (score 2):

The `glob` function does not recognize regular expression style character classes `([Pp], [Ee])`. Instead, it uses `csh`-style wildcard expansion. To accomplish your example task, you'd want to use the syntax

```
glob("C:\\{P,p}{E,e}{R,r}{L,l}")
```

I don't know the implementation details of `glob`, but it seems like it would also need to examine every file in a directory, and would not necessarily be more efficient than your `readdir/grep` idiom.

Or more concisely (again, not necessarily more efficiently), a `glob/grep` idiom:

```
perl -E "say for grep {/C:\\PERL/i} glob('C:\*')"
```

(updated, still not tested)

Comment: Bizarrely, on Windows that emits: `C:{P,p}ERl
C:{P,p}ERL
C:{P,p}Erl
C:{P,p}ErL
C:{P,p}eRl
C:{P,p}eRL
C:{P,p}erl
C:{P,p}erL
`

Comment: Also doesn't handle `C:\PROGRA~1`