# What is isatty() in C for?

Tags: c, linux

Hi can anyone tell me what is the paramter of isatty() in c. 
I have following code, but I don't understand the first output three number would be 1 and all the left is 0.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
                int t=isatty(i);
                printf("%d",t);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read it as `is a tty?`. This may help.

Comment: That is, read *man isatty* -- *"The isatty() function tests whether fd is an open file descriptor referring to a terminal."*

Comment: This is a POSIX function, not from C standard library.

Comment: Thank you! But what is meaning of the parameter taken by isatty()?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A quick look at your man pages would reveal:

```
int isatty(int fildes);

DESCRIPTION
     The isatty() function tests whether  fildes,  an  open  file
     descriptor, is associated with a terminal device.
```

Further investigation would lead you to the discovery that file descriptors 0, 1 and 2 (aka STDIN_FILENO, STDOUT_FILENO and STDERR_FILENO) are by convention set up to point to your terminal when your program is running from a terminal.

Comment: Thank you! Can you tell me how to find where to find which file descriptor each int is referring to?

Comment: there isn't a standard way.

Comment: @Hao9000 If you want the filename referred to by the file descriptor, on Linux you may use `readlink`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188757/getting-filename-from-file-descriptor-in-c)

Comment: This answer doesn't give much more info than what can be found in the man page. However, I'm not quite sure how this would behave in different circumstances. For example, let's say I run a program from my terminal (tty), but redirect its standard output to a file. What would the program get if it ran `isatty(STDOUT_FILENO)`? Can we use this function to test whether the program is being run in a terminal? If so, how? In other words, some _practical_ examples for when this would be used would be nice.

Comment: the man page is probably the best answer. If your output is redirected to a file, STDOUT_FILENO refers to a file. Which is not a terminal.

Comment: Good enough Tom Tanner. Thanks!

Comment: I made a POC of the isatty() function to differentiate when a C utility is launched by cron or by a human user. It works even when the std output is redirected to a file. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73261754/8520235

Answer (score 5):

`isatty()` is a function that returns `1` if the fd - (file descriptor) refers to a terminal.

It comes under the #include

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

Comment: in what way does it not answer the question (in so far as its not significantly worse than some of the other answers here)

Answer (score 1):

It tells whether the file descriptor is connected to a terminal or not.

You can read more about it here: http://linux.die.net/man/3/isatty

Comment: No, it tests whether it is an open file descriptor referring to a terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [ref](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html):

> isatty - test whether a file descriptor refers to a terminal

Answer (score 1):

"*But what is meaning of the parameter taken by isatty()?*"

The parameter is an index into the standard I/O library's table of file descriptors. Indexes 0, 1 and 2 are reserved for `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`. All other indexes refer to file descriptors that can/have been opened by you.

Answer (score 0):

Isatty() is used for checking a fd (file descriptor) belongs to a terminal or command line prompt.
This function gives you binary value 1 when it belongs to a terminal
It uses in codes which contains
unistd.h keywords in header file
isatty() gives you 1 if fd is an open file descriptor referring to a terminal; or else 0 is returned

Answer (score 0):

In case you are still interested, I came across the MSDOS implementation from a few years ago.

```
/*
** Return "true" if fd is a device, else "false"
*/
isatty(fd) int fd; {
  fd;               /* fetch handle */
  #asm
    push bx         ; save 2nd reg
    mov  bx,ax      ; place handle
    mov  ax,4400h   ; ioctl get info function
    int 21h         ; call BDOS
    pop  bx         ; restore 2nd reg
    mov  ax,dx      ; fetch info bits
    and  ax,80h     ; isdev bit
  #endasm
 }
```