# Is there a cross-platform way to check if stdout is being piped into another program in Rust?

Tags: rust, pipe, tty

I'd like to disable colors when the output is piped somewhere else than a terminal.

Comment: To rephrase this: you want to check whether `stdout` is a TTY. You might want to check the `isatty` function or a crate wrapping it for compatibility, eg. https://crates.io/crates/atty.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of Rust 1.70, [`std::io::IsTerminal`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.IsTerminal.html) is available:

```
use std::io::IsTerminal;

fn main() {
    dbg!(std::io::stdout().is_terminal());
}
```

Alternatively, [crossterm has a is_tty() method](https://docs.rs/crossterm/latest/crossterm/tty/trait.IsTty.html), and there's also the [is-terminal crate](https://github.com/sunfishcode/is-terminal) (a maintained fork of `atty`).

Comment: Thanks for sharing this - not having to use a dependency nowadays sounds best! I'd love to see a link to the std documentation and if there are any differences to the isatty function solution

Answer (score 13):

Translated into the POSIX language, your question would be: "is stdout not a TTY", so the answer on *nix can be obtained by [`!isatty(STDOUT_FILENO)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36258285/1026). The [libc](https://crates.io/crates/libc) crate can be used to call this from Rust.

On Windows, it's complicated, so you're better off using the [atty](https://crates.io/crates/atty) crate.

[edit] You can use the `atty` crate  on Linux as well, making it a convenient solution for cross-platform programs.

Comment: Is there any reason to go via `libc`? The atty crate is cross-platform.

Comment: The only reason I can think of is avoiding an extra dependency, while not needing to be cross-platform.

Comment: just tried atty on linux and it works flawlessly