# C Print what file is in the default stdin after using dup2

Tags: c, linux, shell, debugging, dup

I am writing a small shell in C that runs on Linux. Because there are a lot of dups involved, I would like to ask if there is a way to print what is inside position 0. For example if I call **dup2(file_name,0)** is there a way to print the **file_name** so I can use it for debugging?

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the filename from dup2. As you can read [here](http://codewiki.wikidot.com/c:system-calls:dup2) it only returns a `int` value:

```
int dup2(int fildes, int fildes2);
```

What you can do in Linux is:

> You can use [readlink](https://linux.die.net/man/2/readlink) on /proc/self/fd/NNN where NNN is the file
>   descriptor. This will give you the name of the file as it was when it
>   was opened [[here]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188757/getting-filename-from-file-descriptor-in-c)

Or something more creative is creating a `struct` where you can assosiate the `fildes` to a `filename`.

Something like this:

```
struct Files{
   int  fildes;
   char  filename[50];
} files;
```

If you have more then one just create an array and take the one you need every time; in such a way you can always map it with a `filename`.

Comment: Note that not all versions of Unix support the `/proc` file system.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler but this answer is Linux-specific. The OP asked for linux. Do you think I should in anycase write a note?

Comment: I missed that Linux was mentioned in the question, even though it's not in the tags.  You're fine, then.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using  linux operating system,you can show your file description table easily
every process on linux stored /proc/ directory by their process id, fd folder show file description table of process
e.g.

```
ls -l /proc/1405/fd
```

[image: outputlooks like this image]