# How to check opened file path?

Tags: c

Because FILE struct is depended on implementation, is there any fail-proof way to resolve FILE "object" to the path of the file it was create with?

Comment: No. (This space intentionally left blank)

Comment: In general, on Linux (and similar) you may be able to convert FILE* to fd using a the `fileno` call, and then use the answer from here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188757/retrieve-filename-from-file-descriptor-in-c). Fail-proof way? No.

Comment: Normally you don't need this anyway. Your program is in charge and so you know which fle you have opened in the first place. What is your use case?

Comment: @Jabberwocky in my case i should always check the data im working with. i have an object container, which could be dumped to file. this container has the path string to the file inside, but as a fail-proof i was planning on checking if the file path it has matches the one that is tied to the FILE "object"

Comment: @keycattie: I really do not understand what you actually need.. You want to transform a FILE into a path, but why? What is the context / need? You are normally the one providing the path, not wondering about it.

Comment: @virolino the part of my reasoning in the comment above your one. but what i want to add to that is that i do not `fclose()` every time i finish working with the `FILE` "object"

Comment: @keycattie I think your "fail proof" conecpt here is pointless. _You_ `fopen`ed the file (hopefully) including error checks. Once the file is open, it is open and you don't need to do any more checks to verify the file you opened is _actually_ the file you opened.

Comment: @Jabberwocky as long as the pointer to `FILE` can be overwritten with anything else (and in my case that could happen) there is a possibility of my further code to mess up badly. which i was trying to eliminate...

Comment: @keycattie if someone overwrites the area pointed to by a FILE pointer or the file pointer itself, you're in the area of undefined bahaviour and anything can happen anyway, so your check would be really pointless. Even if there was a standard function like `const char *fgetfilename(FILE *file)`, calling this function would result in undefined behaviour if you call it with an invalid or corrupted `FILE` pointer.

Comment: @keycattie: as @ Jabberwocky said, if the FILE structure gets overwritten, then you have much bigger problems to care about. Maybe a full review (including static analysis) is required for your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it is either hard due to `FILE` structure being implementation dependent, or a sign of improperly designed code. As it stands now, `stdlib` does not provide any way of checking this exact thing. There are ways to check file handles, but those are system dependent and are not practical.