# In C, how to delete a file that hasn't been closed yet?

Tags: c, file

I have separate locations in my C program where I call `fopen`, `fwrite` and `fclose`.

When some conditions are met, I want to delete the file I worked on instead of calling `fclose` on it.  However, by the time I reach fclose, it isn't trivial to recreate the file name I used when calling `fopen` so using `remove` isn't practical.

Is there something I can do instead or before calling `fclose` so that in effect the file I opened with `fopen` and used `fwrite` on will not show up on disk in the end?

E.g.

```
f = fopen(filename,"wt");
...
fwrite(f,...)
...
// How can I undo here the effect of fopen and fwrite without knowledge of filename?
```

Comment: If you're using a Unix-like system, just delete it — you're allowed to delete a file that's open.  Windows is a different story, though.

Comment: Do you mean, you actually simply just want to clear the `FILE*` buffer in memory to avoid writing the data in buffer to the file? Because `fopen` already created the file.

Comment: No, there is no standard C way to perform such an action. Even with posix functions it is not possible to delete a file by handle. The main reason behind being, that the file itself and its entries in one or more directories are treated separately.

Comment: I'd try closing the _file descriptor_. After that you should be able to delete the file, and also `fclose` should fail, so it shouldn't matter in which order you do these operations. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fileno.3.html

Comment: Well you know the filename, because you've called `fopen` with a well known filename. Just remember that filename somehow and call `remove(filename)` once you've fclosed the file.

Comment: @Jabberwocky You don't even need to wait - on a Unix system, just call `remove(filename);` right after `fopen()`.  That makes cleanup of temporary files easy - you don't have to.  As long as you don't need to access the file by name, you can still use the `FILE *` handle to read/write from/to the file.

Comment: @AndrewHenle true, but by doing it after the `fclose` you're on the safe side.

Comment: @Jabberwocky `readlink( "/proc/self/fd/N", ... );` just prior to `fclose()` then, as long as the file doesn't get renamed in the meantime.

Comment: Lolo, what do you want to do with the open `FILE *` after the file is deleted?

Comment: depending on the constraints maybe an option: after fopen directly store the filename in a hashtable e.g. with the file descriptor as key, then create a function which returns the filename based on descriptor and with that you can delete the file if necessary - finally you need a function which removes the entry from the hashtable after a fclose / delete operation?

Comment: I don't have any need for `f` once the file is deleted. Yes, I could add some logic in my code to know at the time of `fclose` what the filename is so that I can call `remove` if need be. Or alternatively I can retrieve the filename from the file descriptor itself. My question was whether I could avoid having to retrieve the file name and call `remove` if I haven't already done an `fclose`. Sounds like no, and I should `fclose`, retrieve the file name, and then `remove`.

Comment: @Lolo You'd need to retrieve the name from the descriptor *before* you call `fclose()`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes indeed.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested code, but this should maybe do what you want:

```
// store both file pointer and file name to be able to delete the file
struct file_info {
    const char *filename;
    FILE *fp;
};


struct file_info file; // uninitialized, remember to initialize all fields
file.filename = "whatever"; // consider ownership of this string!
file.fp = fopen(file.filename, "wt");
if (!file.fp) {
    perror("fopen");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); // following code would crash with file.fp=NULL
}
// possibly make the buffer larger with setvbuf to prevent flushing

// do file operations

// abort

// stop any IO on this file descriptor
if (close(fileno(file.fp)) == -1) {
    perror("warning: close fail");
}

// clean up the FILE* structure, the file descriptor should be invalid,
// on condition that you must not open new files between close and fclose!
if (fclose(file.fp) == 0) {
    fputs("warning: fclose success", stderr);
}

// delete after closing the file, otherwise will not work on Windows
if (remove(file.filename) == -1) {
    perror("warning: remove fail");
}
```

Comment: `close(fileno(file.fp))` and then `fclose(file.fp)` is dangerous.  Closing the file descriptor out from under a `FILE *` risks that file descriptor being reused and having its data corrupted and/or closed unexpectedly.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes, if this is multithreaded code, which may open files from other threads, this needs locking. But otherwise, there's nothing which can open a file and re-use the descriptor.

Comment: `open()`, `pipe()`, and `socket()` and `socketpair()` are all async-signal-safe...

Comment: @AndrewHenle The locking is not needed because they wouldn't be. Locking is needed in the multi-threaded scenario, so the file descriptor does not get re-used.

Comment: Locking has nothing to do with it.  Your "there's nothing which can open a file and re-use the descriptor" is wrong.  Signal handlers can safely call `open()` *et al* and reuse the file descriptor value.

Comment: @AndrewHenle In this case they can't do it (create new open file descriptors) safely, it will create a race condition. The code in signal handlers is under the control of the programmer.

Comment: *The code in signal handlers is under the control of the programmer.* Really?!?!  What libraries are you linking in?  How much of the code of a huge project do you have control over?  You're aiming to create Heisenbugs.

Comment: @AndrewHenle If a library messes with signal handlers without application programmer knowing about it, that's already a problem (programmer using same signal) waiting to happen.

Answer (score 0):

If I summarize all comments I got, the answer to my question is as follows.

No, for safe code running on all platforms, once `fopen` has been invoked already, one needs to call `fclose` and then `remove`.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like [Retrieve filename from file descriptor in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188757/retrieve-filename-from-file-descriptor-in-c). Maybe you can find a solution to get the filename there.