# how to get unlinkat(dir_fd, ".", AT_REMOVEDIR) to work?

Tags: c, linux, unlink

I need to unlink an empty directory with

`unlinkat(dir_fd, ".", AT_REMOVEDIR)`

and I am getting `EINVAL errno`, which, according to official GNU documentation, must mean "An invalid flag value was specified in `flags`", which is not the case, as `AT_REMOVEDIR` is (the only) allowed flag.

SSCCE is as follows.  Note, that in the simplest code, I do have the directory name, so I could have used `rmdir`.  In the real situation, I don't have the name, I only have the descriptor, to an empty directory, and I need to remove it - so I have to use `unlinkat` .

`foobar.c`:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int dir_fd =
        open("dir", O_RDONLY | O_PATH | O_DIRECTORY);

    if (-1 == dir_fd) {
        perror("open");
        return(1);
    }
    
    if (unlinkat(dir_fd, ".", AT_REMOVEDIR)) {
        perror("unlinkat");
        fprintf(stderr, "errno %d\n", errno);
        return(1);
    }
}
```

and I get this behaviour:

```
$mkdir dir
$gcc -lc foobar.c
$./a.out
unlinkat: Invalid argument
errno 22
$errno 22
EINVAL 22 Invalid argument
```

and GNU documentation for `unlinkat` says

EINVAL An invalid flag value was specified in flags.

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/2/rmdir `EINVAL
pathname has . as last component.`

Comment: @tkausl so then I have to get the name (it's gonna be a major pain in the a*s) and use `rmdir` , right? No other way?

Comment: @tkausl basically, I forgot about the cardinal rule: if something appears to not follow the documentation as read in ordinary fashion, read it more carefully then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When called with `AT_REMOVEDIR`, [`unlinkat(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/unlinkat) behaves as [`rmdir(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/rmdir), and ultimately fails to the same reasons.

For [`rmdir(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/rmdir):

> EINVAL pathname has .  as last component.

You have seemingly flipped the interface. Looking at your *example* in isolation, it should be

```
/* foobar.c */
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int dir_fd = open(".", O_RDONLY | O_PATH | O_DIRECTORY);

    if (-1 == dir_fd) {
        perror("open");
        return(1);
    }

    if (unlinkat(dir_fd, "dir", AT_REMOVEDIR)) {
        perror("unlinkat");
        fprintf(stderr, "errno %d\n", errno);
        return(1);
    }

    close(dir_fd);
}
```

```
$ mkdir dir
$ ./a.out
```

where a relative *pathname* given to `unlinkat` is resolved relative to the directory referred to by *dirfd*.

(*Or the special value of `AT_FDCWD` could be used for the first argument of `unlinkat` to remove a file relative to the current working directory.*)

This particular example is obviously a rather complex way of doing the same thing `rmdir("dir")` does, and it certainly does not help you if you do not know the name of the directory to be removed.

For your actual *problem*: On Linux, you can try something along the lines of the following example, that uses [`readlink(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/readlink) to read */proc/self/fd/NNN*, where *NNN* is the file descriptor (for which you do not have a name), in order to retrieve a *pathname* for `rmdir`.

(*See: [Retrieve filename from file descriptor in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1188757/2505965)*)

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static int mystery_directory(void)
{
    char dir[] = "XXXXXX";

    if (!mkdtemp(dir))
        return -1;

    return open(dir, O_RDONLY | O_PATH | O_DIRECTORY);
}

int main(void)
{
    /* We have magically arrived at this file descriptor */
    int dir_fd = mystery_directory();

    if (-1 == dir_fd) {
        perror("mystery_directory");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char fdrl[128];
    int len = snprintf(fdrl, sizeof fdrl, "/proc/self/fd/%d", dir_fd);

    if (len < 0 || len >= sizeof fdrl) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Something has gone very wrong.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("procfs entry: <%s>\n", fdrl);

    char path[4096];
    ssize_t r = readlink(fdrl, path, sizeof path - 1);

    if (r < 0) {
        perror("readlink");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    close(dir_fd);
    path[r] = 0;

    printf("Attempting to remove directory: \n\t%s\n", path);

    if (-1 == rmdir(path)) {
        perror("rmdir");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    puts("Success!");
}
```

```
$ pwd
/home/so
$ ./a.out
procfs entry: </proc/self/fd/3>
Attempting to remove directory: 
    /home/so/IOgkes
Success!
```

Comment: I accepted it and yet I downvoted your answer - the reason is, I clearly stated that I don't have the name, so your sample code is pointless (even in more ways than one).  Delete it and I will vote it back up :)

Comment: OK, I see, I knew about the `/proc` thing, but not precisely, I thought it was going to be painful too, but seems OK...