# Get file name by file descriptor

Tags: c++, posix

I was able to get file name by file handle in Win32 with the following code:

```
std::wstring GetFileName() const
{
    TCHAR buf[MAX_PATH];
    // It is not clear what is the difference with FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED.
    const DWORD len = GetFinalPathNameByHandle(m_hFile, buf, MAX_PATH, FILE_NAME_OPENED);

    if (len > MAX_PATH)
    {
        return _T("<Too long path>");
    }

    return buf;
}
```

is there a way to do the same in POSIX?

If I opened a file with a code like this:

```
auto fd = ::open("abc.dat", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
```

how to get the file name by `fd` after that?

Comment: *Is not Windows better than Linux?* [They both have lots of ways of being stupid](https://serverfault.com/questions/1146995/windows-10-symbolic-links-finer-grained-than-developer-mode).  Special permissions are needed to create symbolic links in Windows?  Seriously?!?!?

Comment: Yesterday, you asked [a question about how to port Windows code to POSIX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77395777/7509065) that you ended with "Is not Windows the best operating system?". Today, you asked another question about how to port Windows code to POSIX, and you ended this one with "Is not Windows better than Linux?". Are these legitimate things that have come up as you're trying to port something, or are you just asking these questions polemically? Because the latter isn't allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *[I]s there a way to [get file name by file descriptor] in POSIX?*

No.  There may be OS-specific ways to do this (as with [`/proc` in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188757/retrieve-filename-from-file-descriptor-in-c)), but not POSIX.

If you want to know the name under which a file descriptor was opened/allocated, you can store it yourself for later lookup.  (My inference, possibly mistaken, is that Windows' `GetFinalPathNameByHandle` does a similar lookup, and that's how it deals with deleted or hard linked or renamed files — by simply giving the name under which a file was opened.)