# How to create a product filter in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, filter, vuejs3

Consider the following product array:

```
    [
    {
      "ID": 1,
      "Fuel Source": "Wood",
      "Type": "Freestanding",
      "Model": "F1150",
      "Catalytic": "No",
      "Maximum BTU's Per Hour": 55000,
      "Higher Heating Value Efficiency (HHV)": 0.7,
      "Lower Heating Value Efficiency (LHV)": 0.75,
      "Steady-State Efficiency": "n/a",
      "Link To Unit": "http://www.regency-fire.com/en/Products/Wood/Wood-Stoves/F1150",
      "Key Features": "Large fire viewing area, with heat radiating ceramic glass\nWood-finished handle\nHeavy duty cast hinges that will never bend or break\nSolid forged steel adjustable cam lock ensures a tight door seal over time\nFront mounted air adjustment\nAir operating safety tool\nHigh performance brick-lined firebox reflects heat\nNon-obtrusive air wash curtain keeps glass clean\nHeavy gauge steel log retainers to stop logs from rolling\nWelded ash lip will never bend or break\nRear heat deflector allowing for closer clearances\nMobile home and alcove approved\nDual-burn design creates longer and more complete burns\nBacked by the industry’s most comprehensive Limited Lifetime Warranty",
      "Product Size": "Small",
      "Maximum Log Size": "18\"",
      "Burn Time*": "Up to 8 hours",
      "Firebox Capacity": "1.3 cu. ft.",
      "Hopper Size": "n/a",
      "Emissions (g/hr)": "1.7 g/hr",
      "View Area": "126 sq. in.",
      "Exhaust Size": "6\"",
      "Minimum Fireplace Opening (W x H x D)": "n/a",
      "Fireplace Dimensions (W x H x D)": "24\" x 32-3/16\" x 20\"",
      "Picture Name": "F1150.jpg",
      "Feature Sheet File Name": "F1150 Feature Sheet.pdf",
      "Description": "The Regency Classic Small Wood Stove is perfect for smaller spaces, or for those needing to supplement their current heating system. It's compact footprint does not disappoint in heating capacity; burning efficiently, and extracting all the heat possible from one load of wood. Turn down your furnace and save money with this Regency small wood stove.",
      "Teaser": "A perfect fit for smaller rooms.  This small non-catalytic wood stove, comes with your choice of pedestal or legs and it is available in black or with nickel accents.",
      "Additional Picture Name #1": "F1150-B.jpg",
      "Pricing Reference Name": "001-915"
    },
    {
      "ID": 2,
      "Fuel Source": "Wood",
      "Type": "Freestanding",
      "Model": "F2450",
      "Catalytic": "No",
      "Maximum BTU's Per Hour": 75000,
      "Higher Heating Value Efficiency (HHV)": 0.733,
      "Lower Heating Value Efficiency (LHV)": 78.4,
      "Steady-State Efficiency": "n/a",
      "Link To Unit": "http://www.regency-fire.com/en/Products/Wood/Wood-Stoves/F2450",
      "Key Features": "Large fire viewing area, with heat radiating ceramic glass\nWood-finished handle\nHeavy duty cast hinges that will never bend or break\nSolid forged steel adjustable cam lock ensures a tight door seal over time\nFront mounted air adjustment\nAir operating safety tool\nHigh performance brick-lined firebox reflects heat\nNon-obtrusive air wash curtain keeps glass clean\nWelded ash lip will never bend or break\nRear heat deflector allowing for closer clearances\nMobile home and alcove approved\nDual-burn design creates longer and more complete burns\nBacked by the industry’s most comprehensive Limited Lifetime Warranty",
      "Product Size": "Medium",
      "Maximum Log Size": "18\"",
      "Burn Time*": "Up to 10 hours",
      "Firebox Capacity": "2.3 cu. ft.",
      "Hopper Size": "n/a",
      "Emissions (g/hr)": "2.3 g/hr",
      "View Area": "161 sq. in.",
      "Exhaust Size": "6\"",
      "Minimum Fireplace Opening (W x H x D)": "n/a",
      "Fireplace Dimensions (W x H x D)": "24\" x 36-5/16\" x 27-3/16\"",
      "Picture Name": "F2450.jpg",
      "Feature Sheet File Name": "F2450 Feature Sheet.pdf",
      "Description": "The Regency Classic Medium Wood Stove provides the perfect amount of heat for most spaces. Load wood in this stove front to back or side to side for the optimum convenience. Backed by our Limited Lifetime Warranty, we are confident that the quality workmanship, finest materials and durable construction of all Regency products, will serve your family for years to come.",
      "Teaser": "The F2450 is a Medium non-catalytic wood stove, comes with your choice of pedestal or legs and it is available in black or with nickel accents.",
      "Additional Picture Name #1": "F2450-B.jpg",
      "Additional Picture Name #2": "F2450-C.jpg",
      "Pricing Reference Name": "001-946"
    }
  ]
```

I am currently looping through this array to display all my products. However my shop I have added a filters array to make it more easy to navigate. My filters array has three filters (fuel, form, and size) and is originally loaded using this which uses my products array to get the unique values from the product array for these three fields:

```
  const setFilters = () => {
    filters.value = [
      {
        id: 'Fuel Source',
        name: 'Fuel Type',
        options: [...new Set(products.value.map(item => item["Fuel Source"]))].map((item) => ({ value: item, label: item, checked: false }))
      },
      {
        id: 'Type',
        name: 'Form Factor',
        options: [...new Set(products.value.map(item => item["Type"]))].map((item) => ({ value: item, label: item, checked: false }))
      },
      {
        id: 'Product Size',
        name: 'Size',
        options: [...new Set(products.value.map(item => item["Product Size"]))].map((item) => ({ value: item, label: item, checked: false }))
      },
    ];
    
    return array;
  };
const activeFilters = computed(() => {
  let array = [];
  filters.value.forEach(function(entry){ 
    entry.options.forEach(function(childEntry) {
        if(childEntry.checked == true)
        {
          array.push(childEntry);
        }
    });
  });
  return array;
})
```

This filters array is the v-model for some three sets of radio boxes that are on the shop box. So if a user checks the fuel type wood then that filters array updates for that filter. My issue is I am trying to create a computed property to generate an array for products that should be shown on the page. If no filter is selected then just return all products array but if there is a filter present (ie, activeFilter >0) then it should ensure the products shown contain all the filters. I am not sure how to do this intersection of filters in a efficient manner. Its like I should loop through every product and check if it again every option in the filters array that is checked but I cannot think of how to write that out cleanly without looping inside looping.

```
const filteredProducts = computed(() => {
  if (activeFilters.length == 0){
    return products.value
  } else {
    let productsToShow = [];
    products.value.forEach(function(product){
      let criteria = [];
      filters.value.forEach(function(filter){ 
        filter.options.forEach(function(option){
          if(option.checked == true){
            if(product[filter.name] != option.value){
              //did not meet this checked filter option so add failed to list
              criteria.push(false)
            }
          }
        })
      })
      //check if any values didnt match the filter  and if not length should be 0
      if(criteria.length == 0){
        productsToShow.push(product)
      }
    });
    return array;
  }
});
```

Comment: It's not clear to me (you are using `activeFilters` only once inside `filteredProducts`), anyway you could make more computed properties, avoid the else [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820839/using-return-instead-of-else-in-javascript) and use the right name for your variables (`filteredOptions` instead `array`) to refactor the code, it will be easier to read

Comment: I added an update above with better variable names. I also added a comment as well. Let me know your thoughts as this returns 0 items in array when aany filters are selected. I honestly find using if else at a high level not to bad. Is it bad practice?

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea, but it may not be a good one.

You can call a function when clicking a checkbox. This function takes two parameters: the first parameter is the index of the selected filter, and the second is the index of the product within that filter. Inside the function, you retrieve this element and add it to your list.

Comment: no its not a bad idea. I just thought a computed property did seem kind of conveinant but ultimately this might work as well. Care to work up answer?

Comment: @SA Moosavi, It would be better if you could provide a working example instead of just a theory.