# Dealing with big IF statements in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

Is there any good alternative for the plain `if` statements in PHP? I know about `switch`, but I'll guess that there's some more refined alternative out there that comes handy when working with really big `if` statements.

Thanks a lot,

Comment: How big are your `if` statements? It's possible they can be simplified and depending on the type of logic you are dealing with, there might be alternatives. Nevertheless, if you post some code that would be insightful.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean. Something like ruby's `unless`?

Comment: What do you mean by big? Big conditions, big bodies, or deeply nested?

Comment: Is the condition big or is the code that is to be executed when the condition is true big?

Comment: No the conditions are huge, there's plenty of rows with if_functions that I want to make something better of...

Comment: Can you give an example?  If it's too large post a link to some source code.  It's hard to refractor without an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to improve readability only, then you can always split up the expressions inside the if statement:

```
$exp1 = is_array($var) && isset($var['key']);
$exp2 = is_object($var) && isset($var->key);
$exp3 = substr($string, 0, 4) == 'foo';
$exp4 = ($exp1 || $exp2) && $exp3;
if ($exp4) {}
```

instead of

```
if (((is_array($var) && isset($var['key'])) || (is_object($var) && isset($var->key))) && substr($string, 0, 4) == 'foo') {}
```

Obviously, these are simplified examples, but you get the idea...

Comment: I've seen plenty of expressions that span multiple lines.  This is a great way to improve readability!

Answer (score 13):

If you can't read your algorithm on one screen fold, there's a 99.9% chance you need to refactor your code toward more readability.

Change

```
if ($isHappening) {
  // ... millions of lines of code
} else {
  // .. another million lines of code
}
```

into

```
if ($isHappening) {
  happen();
} else {
  didntHappen();
}

function happen() {
  // millions of lines of code
}

function didntHappen() {
  // another million lines of code
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There really is no magic hammer out there. Your best bet to making them manageable is to break nested ifs into their own functions to make them more readable.

Also, don't forget about [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php). That can save you from having to write a for loop to filter out items.

Also, you can eliminate nesting by using [guard statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268132/invert-if-statement-to-reduce-nesting). You basically invert your if and do a `return` instead (another reason to break conditions into functions).

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the world of Object Orientation :)

```
class Case1 {
   function do() { echo "case 1"; }
}

class Case2 {
   function do() { echo "case 2"; }
}


$object = new Case1();

$object->do();
```

And then, there is dispatching using an array:

```
$choices = array( "case1" => new Case1(), "case2" => new Case2(), ... );

$choices[ $_GET["case"] ]->do();
```

Comment: What @xtofl is advocating is smart usage of polymorphism. Obviously, this is an overly-simplified case, but using polymorphism to re-refactor complex if statements is part of solid OO design.

Comment: I can vouch for this. After some time with OOP, the concept of long, complicated if statements is alien to me. Everything is shorter and simpler now.

Answer (score 1):

Well `if` is `if`, there is not much else out there. Of course `switch` is an alternative but depending on the conditions it might not be applicable.

If you are doing OOP, the [state design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) might be what you need.

Otherwise you have to give more information...

Answer (score 1):

If by "big" you mean large, highly nested "ifs", this is a clear sign of code smell, and you should be looking at OOP and design patterns.