# Any alternative's to multiline if statements?

Tags: php, syntactic-sugar

Are there any alternative patterns for reducing a multi-line if statement to something more readable or presentable? Something like:

```
if ($x == $y
  && $x == $z
  && $y == $v
  && $m == $t
  && $f == $x
  && $h == $g
  && $q == $w
  && $w == $p // etc
)
```

Comment: A refactor may be in order if you're finding yourself comparing that many conditions...

Comment: I don't have write-access to the code that generates the two sets of variables, I just need to check if one set is a duplicate of the other.

Comment: I think that this type of statement is universal and easily understandable. Any "clever" way of doing it would probably sacrifice those traits.

Comment: @chuster: You're telling me you don't know of any easier way to compare two objects as the same other than checking each property individually? Also, this sounds like a perfect opportunity to create an [object comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php) method.

Comment: @kjy112: Thanks, but the rep is just an added bonus to helping others and learning from others' experiences. ;-)

Comment: @brad Creating new objects to hold the variables just so i can compare them seemed like overkill but i am willing to do it if its the right thing to do here.

Comment: @chustar: Personally, I would break that off in to another function. `if (objectsAreEqual($a,$b))` with a defined function solely for comparing seems more legible to me. Then, whichever method you decide on for the comparison is up to you, but gives you freedom of choice across the project, and can benchmark it later for optimizations (while keeping your condition in plain English).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dealing with big IF statements in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813774/dealing-with-big-if-statements-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could compact this particular instance with:

```
if (array($x, $x, $y, $m, $f, $h, $q, $w)
 == array($y, $z, $v, $t, $x, $g, $w, $p))
```

But I'm not sure if this is what you want. Your single letter variable names are a bit abstract.

If you are concerned about readability, then using `and` over `&&` sometimes helps.

Comment: Thanks. The single letter variables are just because I don't want to type out regular variable names.

Comment: My carpel tunnel prefers `&&` personally (I also find it a bit more intuitive than "and", but that's probably just me.)

Comment: @Brad: If that was a common issue for me I would even go so far and make it an URL string `"$x=$y $x=$z $y=$v"` and compare that via an url_parse/array_keys/values wrapper function. Depending on the var types. Certainly a helper function in any case.

Comment: If these are in-fact objects, what's wrong with [traditional comparison](http://www.ideone.com/W31YC)?