# Does inverting the "if" improve performance?

Tags: c#, if-statement, resharper

I've been using [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) for a while now and sometimes it suggests that I invert the `if`. I guess an example would be a better explanation of my situation:

```
public void myfunction(int exampleParam){
    if(exampleParam > 0){
        //Do something with form controls for example.
    }
}
```

Now ReSharper suggests that I invert the `if` to this:

```
public void myfunction(int exampleParam){
    if(exampleParam <= 0)
        return;
    //Do something with form controls for example
}
```

Does this "improve" performance somehow? Or is it just aesthetic?