# Style - if(null) { return } vs. if(!null)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, coding-style

Which of the following blocks of code is the better style?

```
void doSomething(Object foo)
{
    if(foo == null) return;

    .
    .
    .
}
```

or

```
void doSomething(Object foo)
{
    if(foo != null) 
    {
       .
       .
       .
    }
}
```

I know they have the same semantic meaning, but I've seen both styles used around the web and within production code. Are there any big reasons I should use one over the other?

Comment: Resharper always prompts to convert code to the first way to avoid nesting.

Comment: There are no "big" reasons. Do whatever you feel makes your code more readable.

Comment: While this question is opinion-based as coding style question, it already have good answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437307/does-inverting-the-if-improve-performance with reasons to pick one.

Comment: It come down to your team's coding standard

Answer (score 0):

This might be more of religious question. In one camp there's the return early ideology, in the other is the single return per method crowd. Personally I think it depends on how long the method is and if the valid case is the majority the length. If the valid case is the longest part, I tend to return early for the invalid cases.