# Read the files in a folder and then store each user id in a linkedhashset

Tags: java, linkedhashset

I have around `100 files in a folder`. And I am trying to read all those files `one by one`. Each file will have data like this and each line resembles an user id.

```
960904056
6624084
1096552020
750160020
1776024
211592064
1044872088
166720020
1098616092
551384052
113184096
136704072
```

So I need to read that file line by line and then store each user id in a `LinkedHashSet`. I am able to read all the files from a particular folder with the below code. But with the below java code that I wrote, I am not sure how to read those files line by line and then store each user id in a `LinkedHashSet`?

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    File folder = new File("C:\\userids-20130501");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        File file = listOfFiles[i];
        if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
            try {
                String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
                System.out.println(content);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated on this? And any better way to do the same process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `FileUtils`. The class has the method `readLines()` which returns a list of `String`.

You can then add this `List` of String to `LinkedHashSet` by using the `addAll()` method.

Try this -

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
File folder = new File("C:\\userids-20130501");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

Set<String> userIdSet = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
    File file = listOfFiles[i];
    if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
        try {
            List<String> content = FileUtils.readLines(file, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            userIdSet.addAll(content);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Junaid for the suggestion. In your example, it will create a new LinkedHashSet everytime. And I want to keep on appending the user id's to same linkedhashset.

Comment: Changed the code to use the same LinkedHashSet. Hope this is was you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `readLine()` method of `BufferedReader` to read a file line by line as below:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

File folder = new File("C:\\userids-20130501");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

Set<String> userIdSet = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
    File file = listOfFiles[i];
    if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
        try {
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
          String line;
          while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
              userIdSet.add(line);
           }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly then you can do something like below.

```
// Change generic if you want Integer
Set<String> userIdSet = new LinkedHashSet<String>(); 

// Your code


String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
// Creating array by splitting for every new line content
String[] stn = content.split("\\n");
     for(String xx : stn){
        // parse it as Integer if you changed the generic
        // Adding the file content to Set
        userIdSet.add(xx); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a the things I would do different.

- Using an iterator for the files
- The new try statement allows opening up a “resource” in a try block and automatically closing the resource when the block is done. [Ref](http://sellmic.com/blog/2011/07/08/7-new-cool-features-in-java-7/)
- Excluding invalid files with a `continue` statement. This removes one level of nesting. [See this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268132/invert-if-statement-to-reduce-nesting)

All of these changes are highly opinionated of course.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

       Set<Integer> users = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();

       File dir = new File("C:\\userids-20130501");
       for (File child : dir.listFiles()) {
         if (!child.isFile() || !child.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
           continue;
         }

         try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
             new FileReader(child.getPath()))) {

           String id = null;
           while ((id = in.readLine()) != null) {
             users.add(Integer.parseInt(id));
           }
         } catch (IOException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
         }
       }
   }
```