# Java: Best practice to return from a method (via if statement)

Tags: java, methods, return, return-value

I've stumbled across both of these methods however I can't decide which one to ultimately go for.

```
public void myMethod() {
    if(isTrue())
        return;
    // code...
}
```

Vs.

```
public void myMethod() {
    if(!isTrue()) {
        // code...
    }
}
```

Anyone got some exciting news as to which is better practice? I'm just curious as to how people approach this.

Taking a look at [Invert "if" statement to reduce nesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268132) explains the readability, however `Java != C#`, is there any difference?

Comment: I think this is mostly opinionated and will probably get down voted and closed, I always go for the latter option in any case

Comment: http://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html

Comment: The one that makes nested code shorter.

Comment: Completely opinion based. It doesn't harm in choosing any of the way. First one is a little more readable to me as I will know in advance that the method returns if condition is false.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I agree

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invert "if" statement to reduce nesting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268132/invert-if-statement-to-reduce-nesting)

Comment: Both are ok. Use one which suits better to your situation.

Comment: @SachinGupta Indeed it is a duplicate! Didn't know what to search for.

Comment: Similar to @Andrew Piliser's comment, the idea of having guard clauses helps reduce the ["Arrowhead Anti Pattern"](http://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/). I think opting for your first approach is best. See Step 4 of the link provided - "Always opportunistically return as soon as possible from the function"

Answer (score 1):

Dear Karl for readbility and complexity reasons I would say the first way is better:

1. the first option is more clear, it avoids to have a method that is two level of indentation when there are not other statues: isTrue() is the condition of return, and should highlighted instead of having to read the whole method code.
2. with the first option, in general, the ciclomatic complexity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) is lower, epecially if you have a lot of code in the if clause.
3. having an if with negation and then 'isTrue' is less clear than without the negation. It's simpler to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer the second one, the reason being, we are focusing on the actual business logic. It also comes with the pre-requisites that are required to make sure our application works as expected.

```
public void myMethod() {
    if(!isTrue()) {
        // code...
    }
}
```

Saying this I don't mean the the first way is not a got practice. Instead you can say we can log / follow the end-users flow, how they use the application, what are the trends and where they usually go. This also eases code readability.

```
public void myMethod() {
    if(isTrue())
        return;
    // code...
}
```

Coming to the memory management, it does not really matter to JVM as both is ideally going to take the similar execution time.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, we may have to return something in both case - whether the condition is `true` or `false`. Then we can do something like this:

```
public someReturnType someMethod(){

   boolean isTrue = true;

   if(!isTrue){
      //do something which 
      //you want to do when the condition is false

      return;
   }

   //do other thing which you want to 
   //do if the condition is true

   return;
}
```

And more over sometimes we return an `ArrayList` or a `String` from a method then we can do this -

```
public ArrayList<Client> getClient(String city){

   List<Client> clients = //some query that generate ArrayList<Client>
   //do something

  return (null != clients ? clients : Collections.EMPTY_LIST);

  //While returning 'String' then you can do something like -
  //return (null != someString ? someString : ""); 

}
```

The advantage of this approach is - the code using `getClient()` method don't require to check against `null` each time it get a `ArrayList<Client>` from the `getClinet()` method.