# Keep getting error "not all code paths return a value"

Tags: c#

So basically I'm trying to make a quiz game and this subprogram check if the answer is correct. And basically every time i try to run the program in gives me the error that not all code paths return a value even though it is clearly seen that there is a return true; and a return false; statement at the end.

```
private bool CheckIfCorrect(byte questionNum, string answers, string userAnswer)
    {
        int adjustmentToTheScore;

        const int EASY_QUESTION_5 = 1;
        const int MEDIUM_QUESTION_10 = 2;
        const int HARD_QUESTION_15 = 3;
        const int GENERALPOINTS = 100;

        if (userAnswer == "A" || userAnswer == "B" || userAnswer == "C" || userAnswer == "D")
        {
            if (answers == userAnswer)
            {
                if (questionNum <= EASY_QUESTION_5)
                {
                    adjustmentToTheScore = (EASY_QUESTION_5 * GENERALPOINTS / totalTimePassed);

                    userScore += adjustmentToTheScore;
                }
                else if (questionNum <= MEDIUM_QUESTION_10)
                {
                    adjustmentToTheScore = (MEDIUM_QUESTION_10 * GENERALPOINTS / totalTimePassed);

                    userScore += adjustmentToTheScore;
                }
                else if (questionNum <= HARD_QUESTION_15)
                {
                    adjustmentToTheScore = (HARD_QUESTION_15 * GENERALPOINTS / totalTimePassed);

                    userScore += adjustmentToTheScore;
                }
                rightAnswerCount++;

                goalSound.SoundLocation = "Goal_Sound.wav";
                goalSound.Play();

                lblTotalCorrect.Text = Convert.ToString(rightAnswerCount);

                if (fastestAnswer == 0 || totalTimePassed < fastestAnswer)
                {
                    fastestAnswer = totalTimePassed;

                    lblFastestAnswer.Text = Convert.ToString(fastestAnswer) + "(s)";
                }

           else
                {
                    adjustmentToTheScore = 10;

                    userScore = userScore - adjustmentToTheScore;

                    booing.SoundLocation = "Booing.wav";
                    booing.Play();
                }

                lblScore.Text = "Score: " + Convert.ToString(userScore);

                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid answer please put a, b, c or d!");

                return false;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Nesting of conditional statements reduce readability of code, bad habit to code this way.. static code analysis tools would offer  you suggestions so improve your code ... [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268132/invert-if-statement-to-reduce-nesting) some good discussion about this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify what the program wanted to do if the first condition `if (userAnswer == "A" || userAnswer == "B" || userAnswer == "C" || userAnswer == "D")` evaluates to false. since the method should return a value of type `bool` for all scenarios. Hence what you have to do is Add a `return` statement after the `if` it may either `true` or `false` that's up to you. so the snippet will looks like:

```
private bool CheckIfCorrect(byte questionNum, string answers, string userAnswer)
    {
       //init here
        if (userAnswer == "A" || userAnswer == "B" || userAnswer == "C" || userAnswer == "D")
        {
            if (answers == userAnswer)
            {
                if (questionNum <= EASY_QUESTION_5)
                {
                    //Some code
                }
                else if (questionNum <= MEDIUM_QUESTION_10)
                {
                    //Some code
                }
                else if (questionNum <= HARD_QUESTION_15)
                {
                    //Some code
                }
                if (true)
                {
                    //Some code
                }

                else
                {
                    //Some code
                }
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

That error means you have return statements that are conditional and it's possible that the code can never reach those conditions, thus it won't return a value.

Just cut the `return false;` part and paste it after the second curly brace below where it is now.

You'll still get the message box and it will still return `false`. It looks like the only condition where it's `true` is above. The return statements end evaluation of the method scope. So nothing below the `return true` will be evaluated once it hits that line.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `return false` after the very last `else` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You only return true or false if you enter that first `if` statement. You need a `return` at the bottom if you fail the first `if`.

Answer (score 0):

In a non void function, every logical path in the program/method *should* end returning a value to the caller.

In your case, first if block's false condition doesn't return anything, which is causing the `exception`

```
private bool CheckIfCorrect(byte questionNum, string answers, string userAnswer)
{
    int adjustmentToTheScore;

    const int EASY_QUESTION_5 = 1;
    const int MEDIUM_QUESTION_10 = 2;
    const int HARD_QUESTION_15 = 3;
    const int GENERALPOINTS = 100;

    if (userAnswer == "A" || userAnswer == "B" || userAnswer == "C" || userAnswer == "D")
    {
        if (answers == userAnswer)
        {
            if (questionNum <= EASY_QUESTION_5)
            {
                adjustmentToTheScore = (EASY_QUESTION_5 * GENERALPOINTS / totalTimePassed);

                userScore += adjustmentToTheScore;
            }
            else if (questionNum <= MEDIUM_QUESTION_10)
            {
                adjustmentToTheScore = (MEDIUM_QUESTION_10 * GENERALPOINTS / totalTimePassed);

                userScore += adjustmentToTheScore;
            }
            else if (questionNum <= HARD_QUESTION_15)
            {
                adjustmentToTheScore = (HARD_QUESTION_15 * GENERALPOINTS / totalTimePassed);

                userScore += adjustmentToTheScore;
            }
            rightAnswerCount++;

            goalSound.SoundLocation = "Goal_Sound.wav";
            goalSound.Play();

            lblTotalCorrect.Text = Convert.ToString(rightAnswerCount);

            if (fastestAnswer == 0 || totalTimePassed < fastestAnswer)
            {
                fastestAnswer = totalTimePassed;

                lblFastestAnswer.Text = Convert.ToString(fastestAnswer) + "(s)";
            } else
            {
                adjustmentToTheScore = 10;
                userScore = userScore - adjustmentToTheScore;

                booing.SoundLocation = "Booing.wav";
                booing.Play();
            }

            lblScore.Text = "Score: " + Convert.ToString(userScore);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid answer please put a, b, c or d!");
            return false;
        }
    }

    return false; // this is required.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private bool CheckIfCorrect(byte questionNum, string answers, string userAnswer)
        {
            int adjustmentToTheScore;

            const int EASY_QUESTION_5 = 1;
            const int MEDIUM_QUESTION_10 = 2;
            const int HARD_QUESTION_15 = 3;
            const int GENERALPOINTS = 100;

            if (userAnswer == "A" || userAnswer == "B" || userAnswer == "C" || userAnswer == "D")
            {
                if (answers == userAnswer)
                {
                    if (questionNum <= EASY_QUESTION_5)
                    {
                        adjustmentToTheScore = (EASY_QUESTION_5 * GENERALPOINTS / totalTimePassed);

                        userScore += adjustmentToTheScore;
                    }
                    else if (questionNum <= MEDIUM_QUESTION_10)
                    {
                        adjustmentToTheScore = (MEDIUM_QUESTION_10 * GENERALPOINTS / totalTimePassed);

                        userScore += adjustmentToTheScore;
                    }
                    else if (questionNum <= HARD_QUESTION_15)
                    {
                        adjustmentToTheScore = (HARD_QUESTION_15 * GENERALPOINTS / totalTimePassed);

                        userScore += adjustmentToTheScore;
                    }
                    rightAnswerCount++;

                    goalSound.SoundLocation = "Goal_Sound.wav";
                    goalSound.Play();

                    lblTotalCorrect.Text = Convert.ToString(rightAnswerCount);

                    if (fastestAnswer == 0 || totalTimePassed < fastestAnswer)
                    {
                        fastestAnswer = totalTimePassed;

                        lblFastestAnswer.Text = Convert.ToString(fastestAnswer) + "(s)";
                    }

               else
                    {
                        adjustmentToTheScore = 10;

                        userScore = userScore - adjustmentToTheScore;

                        booing.SoundLocation = "Booing.wav";
                        booing.Play();
                    }

                    lblScore.Text = "Score: " + Convert.ToString(userScore);

                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid answer please put a, b, c or d!");

                    return false;
                }

            }
            else  
            {
            return false; --- add for first if condition
            }
    }
```