# How do I create priority pathfinding system without If statements

Tags: unity-game-engine

I recently began a new project, which is almost finished. As far as the code goes, all I need to do is add AI to the game. I chose *A** *pathfinding* because it was the best option for me, but I also added enemy personalities to make it more interesting. In essence, based on the enemy's personality, it will either: stay in the fight, go heal, or look for other enemies. I am aware that I can use *if statements*, but I do not want complicated, difficult-to-read code. Please respond if you have any suggestions for how I could put this into practice, thanks in advance.

Here is the code, P.S. the code is not finished yet this is just a test:

```
private enum Personality { Proud, Smart, Dumb }
private Personality personality;

public bool lowHP;
public bool inDanger;
public bool shouldMove;

public bool canCallSupport = true;

public Transform target;
public Transform healStation;
public Transform swarm;

public float scanRadius;
public float alertRadius;

public LayerMask whatIsSupport;
public LayerMask whatIsHeal;

private AIDestinationSetter destinationSetter;

private void Awake()
{
    destinationSetter = GetComponent<AIDestinationSetter>();
}

private void Update()
{
    if (!lowHP)
    {
        destinationSetter.target = target;
    }
    else if (lowHP)
    {
        if (!canCallSupport)
        {
            if (ScanForHelp(whatIsHeal) == null)
                return;
            else
                destinationSetter.target = ScanForHelp(whatIsHeal);
        }
        else if(canCallSupport)
        {
            if (ScanForHelp(whatIsSupport) == null)
                return;
            else
                destinationSetter.target = ScanForHelp(whatIsSupport);
        }
    }
}

private void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    Gizmos.color = Color.green;
    Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, scanRadius);
    Gizmos.color = Color.red;
    Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, alertRadius);
}

private Transform ScanForHelp(LayerMask mask)
{
    Transform closestHelp;

    RaycastHit2D[] hit = Physics2D.CircleCastAll(transform.position, scanRadius, Vector2.right, 0.1f, mask);
    Debug.Log(hit.Length);

    closestHelp = hit[0].transform;
    foreach (RaycastHit2D h in hit)
    {
        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, h.transform.position) < (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, closestHelp.position)))
        {
            closestHelp = h.transform;
        }
    }

    if (closestHelp == null)
        return null;

    return closestHelp;
}

private void CallSupport()
{
    RaycastHit2D[] hit = Physics2D.CircleCastAll(transform.position, alertRadius, Vector2.right, 0.1f, whatIsSupport);
    foreach (RaycastHit2D h in hit)
    {
        h.collider.TryGetComponent<AIDestinationSetter>(out AIDestinationSetter destinationSetter);
        destinationSetter.target = target;
        h.collider.TryGetComponent<AIPath>(out AIPath path);
        path.canMove = true;

    }
    lowHP = false;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invert "if" statement to reduce nesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268132/invert-if-statement-to-reduce-nesting)

Comment: What you need FSM or Behaviour tree as i understand.